# Why does the excel and scientific calculator have different results in getting log?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

My formula in excel is `=LOG(100,3.322) = 3.8358`

But on scientific calculator `3.322log100 = 6.644`

Why it is different, is there anything wrong with my formula?

Comment: Your not two different log calculations.  The second argument is the base, the formula you said you used, isn’t the base

Answer (score 3):

## Logarithms in Excel formulae

The form [`=LOG(a, b)`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/log-function-4e82f196-1ca9-4747-8fb0-6c4a3abb3280) gives the result of the logarithm of value `a` in base `b`.

In your case, you are getting the value of log<sub>3.322</sub> 100 =  3.8358

You can confirm this with [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(3.322,100)) (which takes the arguments in reverse order):

[image: wolframalpha result]

## Why 6.644 on a calculator?

If you input `3.322log100` without any special modifiers, your calculator is almost certainly treating it as:

> 3.322 * log<sub>10</sub>100
>
> ⇒ 3.322 * 2
>
> 6.644